# Wireshark stuck on 'loading module preferences' on mac

Tags: file, freeze, wireshark, preferences, corruption

Yesterday I tried decrypting a TLS connection on Wireshark on Mac (RSA key lists) but it was loading without doing it so I closed and reopened the app but since then it is stuck on 'Loading Module Preferences'. I tried uninstalling it, opening it through the terminal, using sudo, nothing works and I couldn't find help for mac, only for windows. Someone said it might be a corrupted file that could be accessed through .../App Data/Roaming/Wireshark/Preferences but there is no such path on mac.

Has anyone an idea to solve my issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hit this issue. Solved it by deleting the last line in the ~/.wireshark/ssl_keys file (it was the only entry in my case).